MeasureIt Tool: Rendered font size doesn't match viewport
I have an object with multiple MeasureIt annotations. When I render MeasureIt and look at it in the compositor the font size is way bigger. Override is turned off, all font sizes are the same. Render format is at 100%. Image size 1200 x 1080. When I do use Override, the same problem happens. Does this have anything to do with the camera settings? I am absolutely stumped.


